# How to use scalar valued function in case when expression in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT a.UserID,
Sum(Case when UserStatus IN('Out of office','On vacation') then ... ELSE 0 END) as 'Total Out',
Sum(Case when UserStatus IN('Project X','Project Y','Project Z') then ... ELSE 0 END) as 'Total Project'
FROM UserLog a
WHERE a.DateColumn between @start AND @end GROUP BY a.UserID
```

This query is giving me correct answer. but the problem is in case expression. My variables are dynamic and can be changed. So i create a table which has sub states and base states

here is a part of my table

```
BaseState           Substate
Total Out |    Out of office
Total Out |    On vacation
Total In  |    Project X
Total In  |    Project Y
Total In  |    Project Z
Total UK  |    Project X
Total UK  |    Project Y
.
.
.
```

I tried to use subquery for this as below.

```
SELECT a.UserID,
Sum(Case when UserStatus IN(Select Substate FROM StateTable WHERE BaseState = 'Total Out') then ... ELSE 0 END) as 'Total Out',
Sum(Case when UserStatus IN(Select Substate FROM StateTable WHERE BaseState = 'Total In') then ... ELSE 0 END) as 'Total In'
FROM UserLog a
WHERE a.DateColumn between @start AND @end GROUP BY a.UserID
```

It give error about "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery".

I made a function for returning value as 'Out of office','On vacation'. My function is below

```
USE [AgentPerformance]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Status]
(
    @gelen varchar(50)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @donen NVARCHAR(200);
    Select @donen = Left(Main.[SubState],Len(Main.[SubState])-1)
From
    (
        Select distinct ST2.BaseStateName, 
            (
                Select ''''+RTRIM(ST1.SubStateName)+'''' + ',' AS [text()]
                From dbo.[SubState] ST1
                Where ST1.BaseStateName = ST2.BaseStateName
                ORDER BY ST1.BaseStateName
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) [SubState]
        From dbo.[SubState] ST2
    ) [Main] WHERE BaseStateName = @gelen


    RETURN @donen;
END
```

Normally it is returning same as 'Out of office','On vacation' for Total Out when i use normally as a column. But when i tried to write into IN it gaves same error Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

How can i use subquery or function in SUM(CASE WHEN(logic)) <-- logic

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use a subquery or function, why not use a *join*:

```
SELECT a.UserID,
Sum(Case when st.BaseState = 'Total Out' then ... ELSE 0 END) as 'Total Out',
Sum(Case when st.BaseState = 'Total In' then ... ELSE 0 END) as 'Total In'
FROM UserLog a
INNER JOIN StateTable st
ON a.UserStatus = st.Substate
WHERE a.DateColumn between @start AND @end
GROUP BY a.UserID
```

At this point you may also want to consider whether to use `PIVOT` to simplify this further over the explicit pivoting you're currently performing via `SUM(CASE...`

Comment: what if multiple substates in one base state? I edit my table inside of question u can check.. Think if status = Project X how can i get correct value?

Comment: @EnderAriç - what makes you think it will fail? The join for any row from `UserLog` with `Project X` to the `StateTable` table will then produce two results in the result set before grouping. One of those will have `Total In` and the other will have `Total UK` and each will contribute to their *appropriate* `SUM()` expression.

Comment: I my status is Project X it has to calculate with Total In and Total Uk. But it is only getting the first row on table. I can calculate data about Project X in Total Uk with this condition

Comment: @EnderAriç - I'm sorry, I'm not understanding what problem you're trying to describe. Perhaps if you add some *sample data* and *expected results* to the question it'll make it clearer? (Of course, it may also help to know what's in the `...` inside your `CASE` expressions)